# How can I show the adjacent cards in scrollView?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement a swiper in react native, where cards are arranged horizontally and users can swipe left/right to see the next card coming from adjacent edge.

Something similar to this http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VmFqdeN95E4

I have a scrollView with each cards width equal to device width, so each card can be swiped to reveal next/previous card.

But how can I show the adjacent cards in the same viewpoint?

Are there any props in scrollView to achieve this? (using snapToInterval and snapToAlignment doesn't go well if pagingEnabled)

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are using iOS you can combine the ScrollView properties `snapToInterval={somethingSmallerThanDeviceWidth}` and `snapToAlignment` to create this effect. Cards then need to be smaller than device width of course.

I've created a [RNPlay example using this technique](https://rnplay.org/apps/psad7g):

[image: RNPlay preview]

Comment: Tried it out https://rnplay.org/apps/8F1r8Q .. but still missing something.. Can you spot it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a gif and RNPlay example.

Comment: This is neat!, But with pagingEnabled={true} it doesn't go well (because it scrolls to any card based on scroll velocity), any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use `pagingEnabled` with this because it will force you to scroll in full width increments. Using `decelerationRate={0}` like in the demo will have a similar effect or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Solution works perfectly without pagingEnabled, but my use case was little more specific to prevent revealing other cards (after I updated question). Digging little deeper https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1362 (at 7th comment) which even explains how snapToInterval works, I could get to fit my case by overriding onResponderRelease function.

Comment: @oblador is there any way to implement this on react-native android

Comment: @KarthickKumar: Not as easy as this way unfortunately, but you could probably replicate it with PanResponder.

Comment: @oblador It would be very helpful, if provide any working example in RNPlay

Comment: Can you provide same functionality in react-native android with RNPlay. or suggest me any other way

Comment: It is working absolutely fine in android. who told that it does not work in react-native android. did he try ???

Comment: Works well in RNPlay.. I can't get the swipe to 'complete' in iOS simulator though. It just keeps snapping back to the first Card. Even when I remove the snapTo props as well as the deceleration one. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @John ran into the same thing. To fix, remove `flex: 1` from `style.content`

Comment: I've updated the code to work on latest RN. Works fine on iOS but on Android it doesn't stop scrolling on each card: https://rnplay.org/apps/NRfCUA

Comment: Can you please update the link of rnplay ? Thanks @oblador

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need all of these in your scroll view:

```
horizontal = {true}
decelerationRate = {0}
snapToInterval = {200}
snapToAlignment = {'center'}
```

Check the expo for detailed implementation
https://snack.expo.io/H1CnjIeDb

Unfortunately, this does not work on Android at the moment. Hopefully, they will support it in the future.